# AWS on Sing Out request also end session in Shibboleth

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, shibboleth

I configured SAML authentication using [this guide](http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-whitepaper-single-sign-on-integrating-aws-open-ldap-and-shibboleth.pdf). My problem is that to logout from AWS I have to do 2 steps.

1. Sing Out from AWS console
2. End session in Shibboleth accessing logout link *https://idp.example.com/idp/profile/Logout*

Can I configure somehow in AWS Console to redirect to upper link on `Sing Out` action?